# Azure SQL - Calculate stock level based on previous date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have transactions table that looks like below. I need to create a stored procedure that will calculate the `StockLevel` column.

The dates are consecutive (always 1 day gap) and the formula is :

```
StockLevel = yesterdayStockLevel + AIn - AOut
```

Sample data:

```
Date  | ArticleId | AOut | AIn | StockLevel
Aug 1       1         1     10    10 - 1 = 9
Aug 2       1         2     0     9  - 2 = 7
Aug 3       1         1     0     7  - 1 = 6
Aug 4       1         2     0     6  - 2 = 4
Aug 5       1         3     5     4  - 3 + 5 = 6
Aug 6       1         0     0     6  - 0 = 6
```

I prefer to run it on SQL (if possible) and not use cursor (if possible).

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Select Date, ArticleID, AOut, AIn, AInSum-AOutSum as StockLevel
From (
   Select *, 
    sum(AOut)over (Partition by ArticleId Order by Date) AOutSum,
    sum(AIn)over (Partition by ArticleId Order by Date) AInSum
   From yourTabble 
     ) X
```

Comment: Where do you get yesterday's stockLevel? for me it doesn't work.

Comment: what will be your yesterday's stockLevel for first record ?